# Schedule local notification on IF condition

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

My goal is to set the specific schedule time depending on IF condition.

Here's how i do it inside the app:

```
if myarray[myarray.count-1].last == "longnotification"  {
                    print("It's true")
                    let interval = 24*60*60
                    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: interval)
                    localNotification.alertBody = some text
                    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

                } else {
                    print("It's not true")
                    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
                    localNotification.alertBody = some text
                    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
                    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
                }
```

Basically, if the array's last value is "longnotification" the notification should be scheduled to fire after 24*60*60 seconds, if not - it should fire quickly after 60 seconds. But they should be mutually exclusive.

The issue is - the app schedules both notifications despite the condition.

How would you approach this seemingly simple task, guys?

Thank you.

Comment: Dies it print both "true" and "not true"?

Comment: I think Nate is right.  I think you are executing this code multiple times and at least one time the last item is "longnotification" and at least one other time, the last item is not.  Meaning you are programmatically creating both notifications.  Either that, or you are creating the second notification somewhere else in your code.  In other words, if the code block above is only executing once, you will only get one notification.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: @wottle that's i was executing it multiple times. it's like becoming blindfolded while doing a lot of code. thank you for clarification!